# How Can I do a for with many variables

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to know how I can do this for in Kotlin:

```
for(int i=arr.length-1, j=0; i>=0 && j<reverse.length; i--, j++){
    reverse[j] = arr[i];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are Using IntelliJ Idea, you can use [Java to Kotlin code conversion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/converting-a-java-file-to-kotlin-file.html). Result for your code is:

```
var i = arr.length - 1
var j = 0
while (i >= 0 && j < reverse.length) {
    reverse[j] = arr[i]
    i--
    j++
}
```

But if all you need is reverse of your array, then you can just call Array's method [reversedArray](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reversed-array.html).

```
val arr = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
val reversed = arr.reversedArray()
```

Comment: **reversedArray** returns new Array.
**reverse** shuffles the same array

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know u can't have multiple indexes in for loop

As a solution u can use Array.reverse() function or just calculate the second index:

```
    val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)

    val lastIndex = array.size - 1
    for (i in 0..lastIndex)
        array[lastIndex - i] = array[i]
```

[**for** syntaxis](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#for)